# How to always see all band values with Identify Features of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, identify

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the Identify Features tool in QGIS to show the band values for all the layers shown in the results window?

To clarify, whilst I have several bands "showing" in the results window, the actual values for all but the topmost layer are folded away.

Having to unfold the info each time I click on a new location is getting pretty tiresome.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the Identity features tool. Maybe you can make a feature request for it at the QGIS bugtracker http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: I wasn't too optimistic. It's not a major omission, just a peculiarity so I'm not sure whether time and effort should really be put in to addressing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the bands separately and you want that when consulting with the identification tool it shows you the value of all the bands. You have several options.

1.- **The solution for your case is:**
Go to the bottom of the Identification window, in the View option select Table, it will show you the name of the layer, the band, and the pixel value for that layer.
[image]

2- **Other option is to create a virtual raster**, it's a layer joining all the bands but without creating a new file.

[image]
When consulting it will show you the pixel value of all the raster layers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Raster Value Tool to do this.

Comment: I think it does provide an answer, but only barely. It should have more details -- an outline of how the tool works or what it does, a link to documentation or help page, etc.

Comment: I'd say this IS the answer for this question.