# How to get all band values with Identify tool of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, identify

This question is similar to [How to always see all band values with Identify Features of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57146/is-it-possible-to-always-see-all-band-values-with-identify-features), but is for ArcGIS.

I have a multiband raster image, with more than three bands, and I would like to use the identify tool to get all the band values, not just the three bands that are displaid.

Of course, the workaround is to add each individual band or several 3-bands composites, but then I need to have those bands visible as well (which slows down the visualization) or to identify all layers (which slow down the identify). Furthermore, in this case, I have to click in the identify window, which takes me some time.

As a more generic feature, it would be great to have on the fly pixel based map algebra in the identify tool. But this is one step further.

Comment: Maye be a bit modified version of http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t00000097000000

Comment: @msi_g thanks, but the problem is the same as with identify : you only show what is rendered.

Comment: It doesn't display them all at once (separate tabs for each band), but there is the [Pixel Inspector](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_the_Pixel_Inspector/009t00000097000000/). Not sure if it will offer any time improvements over the workaround though. Short of that, converting the raster to a table and performing lookups on that is the only way I can think to do it. It does seem there might be a couple of options in QGIS, such as the Value Tool, if that's an option.

Comment: @ChrisW : msi_g also mentioned Pixel inspector, which is a useful link, but in my case I would like to have all values in one window (like in the extract signature of ENVI, for example). Imagine that you have a Landsat with 7 bands or a time series with 52 weeks, that's a lot of tabs...

Comment: @ChrisW yes, the value tool in QGIS would do the job (I posted the link to this question), but I was wonderig if a similar feature was available in ArcGIS. My raster are unfortunately too big to be converted in vector. Not sure I undestand what you mean with converting raster to table.

Comment: Oops. I swore I clicked that link and it took me to a QGIS question. Guess I wasn't paying attention. Someone might have written a custom tool somewhere, but short of the data conversion I don't know of any way to do it natively in Arc. What I meant with converting raster to table was literally just that - each pixel is a record, each band is a column. It's not practical for large pixel dimensions, but it's the only thing I could think of to let you query one place for all the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the bands were raster, rather than directly adding the entire raster.This way you can see all of the band values.
[image: Add bands and Identify tool setting]

Comment: thank you for your answer, it illustrates my workaround but as I said I would like to avoid adding all individual bands, because 1) I also need the color composite, so this adds more than necessary and 2) if I use "all layers" or "visible layers", there other layers that I don't want to identify, thus it takes more time (I don't want to wait 15 sec everytime I do "identify"